# Endless loop while reading input stream

Tags: java, sockets

I would like to print all of the text that is being written onto the input stream. At the end of the text I would like for the loop to terminate so that it can accept more user input. For some reason my while loop is never terminated and infinitely stalls my program. How do I write the while loop so that it terminates when there is no more text to print out?

```
public static void open() throws IOException {
    sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(arg[1]), Integer.parseInt(arg[2])));
    InputStream stream = sock.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String output;
    while ((output = buff.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The peer hasn't closed the connection, so the loop never terminates.

Comment: Oh I see. How do think I should resolve this to get my desired functionality.

Comment: Err, get the peer to close the connection? Or don't loop? What's the protocol?

Comment: Well I would like the connection to remain open because I would still like to transfer data. I really just want the loop to close once the readLine() function stops receiving text, is that possible?

Comment: I have no idea. Answer my question. What's the protocol? Implement the protocol correctly and the problem is solved. At the movement you're just assuming an indefinite byte-stream.

Comment: ^^ what @EJP says.  What do you mean by 'stops receiving text'?  How would the readLine() function know when that has happened without closing the connection from the client?  Either do that, or send something from the client that indicates end-of-stream, (eg. sending an 'empty' line could be a signal that the loop needs to exit).

Answer (score -1):

Where is the problem? If Im not wrong with your code the while loop will be finished when you don't receive data on your socket.

Maybe your socket always has requests?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The problem is that 'open()' is being called from within a switch statement and the rest of the switch statement underneath the call to open is never able to run. For example if I try to connect to ftp.microsoft.com, the initial FTP header for Microsoft will be displayed but the while loop still won't terminate so that I can enter more input.

Comment: You *are* wrong. The loop will terminate when the peer closes the connection, and not before, unless there is an exception. It won't terminate when the peer merely stops sending data. It will block.